# How to change K8S default service account permissions?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

My team recently found out that the `default` service account, managed by K8S and associated by default to pods, had full read and write permissions in the cluster. We could list secrets from the running pods, create new pods....

We found this strange, as we thought the `default` service account had no permissions whatsoever or even just read permissions. So we decided to search through the cluster for role bindings or cluster role bindings associated with that service account, but we could find none.

In a K8S cluster, doesn't the `default` service account have a basic role binding associated with it? Why don't we have any? And if we don't have any, why does the service account have full permissions on the cluster, instead of none at all? Lastly, how can we modify it so it has no permissions in the cluster?

Just to make it clear: we have multiple namespaces in our cluster, each one having its own `default` service account. However, none of them have any role bindings associated with them and they all have full cluster permissions.

Comment: I have a few questions:
1) There are no RoleBindings or ClusterRoleBindings at all?
2) Are you using a managed Kubernetes service or have you installed the cluster yourself?

Comment: 1) we have 4 RoleBindings accross all namespaces and 13 ClusterRoleBindings, all created either by K8S, tools we have installed, and others manually created by previous people in the project. None associated with the default accounts though 2) It is our own cluster. It was set up using kops

Comment: Follow-up to question n°2: did you enable RBAC support when creating the cluster? By default, kops does not enable RBAC. With RBAC disabled, all service accounts have unrestricted permissions.

Comment: Yeah, we did not. I went through the kube-api-server and the authorization mode was `AlwaysAllow`. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, by default, kops sets up clusters with the K8S API server authorization mode set to `AlwaysAllow`, meaning any request, as long as it is successfully authenticated, has global admin permissions.

In order to fix this, we had to change the authorization mode to `RBAC` and manually tweak the permissions.

Thank you to [@ArthurBusser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12747111/arthur-busser) for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look through your RoleBindings/ClusterRoleBindings. Probably there's a default SA somewhere.

Unfortunately there is no built in solution to search for ClusterRoles of a user, but you can use below script

```bash
function getRoles() {
    local kind="${1}"
    local name="${2}"
    local namespace="${3:-}"

    kubectl get clusterrolebinding -o json | jq -r "
      .items[]
      |
      select(
        .subjects[]?
        |
        select(
            .kind == \"${kind}\"
            and
            .name == \"${name}\"
            and
            (if .namespace then .namespace else \"\" end) == \"${namespace}\"
        )
      )
      |
      (.roleRef.kind + \"/\" + .roleRef.name)
    "
}
```

```text
$ getRoles Group system:authenticated
ClusterRole/system:basic-user
ClusterRole/system:discovery

$ getRoles ServiceAccount attachdetach-controller kube-system
ClusterRole/system:controller:attachdetach-controller
```

Comment: I have done that. Not a single one of the existing RoleBindings or ClusterRoleBindings is associated with any of the default service accounts. Is there any other way these permissions may be defined?